# Tensor("pow:0", ...) must be from the same graph as Tensor("Cast_2:0", ...)

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

I am trying to model something which needs to do the definite integration. The code is showing as below:

```
import tensorflow as tf

from numpy import pi, inf
from tensorflow import log, sqrt, exp, pow
from scipy.integrate import quad  # for integration

def risk_neutral_pdf(phi, a, S, K, r, sigma, Mt, p_dict):

    phii = tf.complex(0., phi)

    A = tf.cast(0., tf.complex64)
    B = tf.cast(0., tf.complex64)

    p_dict['gamma'] = p_dict['gamma'] + p_dict['lamda'] + .5
    p_dict['lamda'] = -.5

    for t in range(Mt-1, -1, -1):
        temp = 1. - 2. * p_dict['alpha'] * B
        A = A + (phii + a) * r + p_dict['omega'] * B - .5 * log(temp)
        B = B * p_dict['beta'] + (phii + a) * (p_dict['lamda'] + p_dict['gamma']) - \
            .5 * p_dict['gamma']**2. + (.5*((phii + a) - p_dict['gamma'])**2. / temp)

    return tf.real(S**a * (S/K)**phii * exp(A + B * sigma**2.) / phii)

p_dict={'lamda': 0.205, 'omega': 5.02e-6, 'beta': 0.589, 'gamma': 421.39, 'alpha': 1.32e-6}

S = 100.
K = 100.
r = 0.
Mt = 0
sq_ht = sqrt(.15**2/252.)
sigma = sq_ht

P1 = tf.py_func(lambda z: quad(risk_neutral_pdf, z, inf, args=(1., S, K, r, sigma, Mt, p_dict))[0],
                [0.], tf.float64)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    res = sess.run(P1)
    print(res)
```

The result returns "InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): ValueError: Tensor("pow:0", shape=(), dtype=float32) must be from the same graph as Tensor("Cast_2:0", shape=(), dtype=complex64)." However, no matter how I change the code or reference the solution in ["ValueError: Tensor A must be from the same graph as Tensor B"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36551936/valueerror-tensor-a-must-be-from-the-same-graph-as-tensor-b?rq=1), it does not work. I am wondering if I did wrong when putting the `tf.reset_default_graph()` at the top place or should the code needs be done some changes.

Thank you. (Tensroflow version: 1.6.0)

**Update:** 
I find that the **sigma** variable has been sqrt before passing into the risk_neutral_pdf function and be powered when return which is not necessary. So after modifying the return to `return tf.real(S**a * (S/K)**phii * exp(A + B * sigma) / phii)` and the sq_ht to `.15**2/252.`. The error changes to **"TypeError: a float is required"**, which I think caused by **quad** and **Tensor**. Any ideas to solve??

Many thanks.